I cannot deduce why I've been banned from asking questions
I've been blocked from asking questions here, but there seems to be no legitimate reason why. (I realize 'legitimate' is subjective here, but that's the way I see it.)
I've posted six questions in the past eight years, with one of them downvoted and closed as off-topic five years ago. I've reviewed the other five just now for quality against these guidelines:

All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have already tried.

I've also verified that the five are indeed on-topic:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
None has received a down-vote or a close-vote, nor any negative feedback. In fact, people were very helpful and accommodating.
I do seem to remember somewhat recently deleting a post that had received a close vote, but I'm unable to find anything about that in order to confirm. Apparently those records are hidden from me.
In any case, I'm surprised and dismayed that a single five-year-old closed question along with a close vote, especially on a post that I deleted and is no longer visible to the community, should be allowed to outweigh my other good history. In fact, the one closed question even received a quite satisfactory answer.
As far as getting reinstated, I'm at a loss as to how any of the open posts can be improved. They're all very detailed, they all drew significant engagement from the community, and they're all on-topic. What more can be done?
If the five-year-old single closed post and the single close vote on the now-deleted post are the culprits here—and I argue again that that's overly harsh if so—requiring the situation to be 'fixed' is asking for the impossible.
What can I do about this?

Thank you somebody, whoever you are :-)

Maybe you have posted other questions which were deleted more than 60 days ago? You are probably not able to see them any more, as long as you don't reach >10K rep  (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted). I cannot see them, too, I guess a diamond mod can.

.. anyway, I now took the time to read some of your questions and gave the ones I liked an upvote, maybe it helps.

@DocBrown — Mr. Owens was kind enough to send a link to my past deleted posts. I was taken aback to see how many there were. Apparently my memory doesn't serve as well as it used to. Thanks for the upvotes, I really appreciate it. And for taking the time to read my posts.

It looks like you are no longer blocked from asking new questions, but you have more than 6 questions. You have posted a total of 13 questions, of which 6 are currently not deleted. Although all 6 of those are 0 or positively scored, the deleted questions tend to be negatively scored. You should be able to view all of your deleted questions here. If you can't view that and want a list, let me know and I can post the list here, but I don't want to start with publicly posting your deleted question history.

Goodness, I guess my posting finger got away from me! I had no idea I'd deleted that many over the years. Thanks for the list. But it begs the question: if the ban (mine is now lifted, thanks to Doc Brown) is calculated on the scoring of at-the-time-deleted posts, how is the hapless wretch to escape from the clutches of that prison cell, other than to rely on the graces of a Good Samaritan to chance along and pull him to safety (as happened with my case)? Isn't it a bit unfair for the algorithm to consider deleted posts in its calculations?

@InteXX The algorithm is global across SE sites and not publicly described. We only suspect a few things about it. In some cases, time passing will lift the block.

"The algorithm is global across SE sites" Goodness, I had no idea! I'm surprised I hadn't heard of it until now, after all these years. Thanks for the info.
